# Duplicate Dll's

Tags: .net, sitecore, gac, yaf

I am trying to integrat Sitecore with YAF ... 
I am running into a non-program specific error and I am hoping someone can help me.

I run my program and I recieve the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'YAF.Forum' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b359048\ea17b5f1\assembly\dl3\698b7e4b\be26b750_b845ce01\YAF.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6b359048\ea17b5f1\App_Code.m3lcmhyi.dll'

Source Error:



Line 18:     <img src="~/images/YAFLogo.jpg" runat="server" alt="YetAnotherForum" id="imgBanner" /><br/>
Line 19:     <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Line 20:         <YAF:Forum runat="server" ID="forum"></YAF:Forum>   
Line 21:     </form>
Line 22: </body>
```

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MEAU_YAF\Website\yaf\default.aspx    Line: 20

Now, I have been told to clear the Global Assemblies Cache ... which i am willing to do, but when i go look in

c:/windows/assembly ... i am not finding anything resembling my application or the Public token key. Based on the error above... what am I looking for? 
please advise.
Regards,